# Is there any way to make sure certain tasks are not executed in parallel?

Tags: python, python-2.7, celery

I'm writing a Celery task that will run some tests on the pull requests created in BitBucket.
My problem is that if a pull request is updated before my task finishes it will trigger the task again and so I can end up having two tasks running tests on same pull request at the same time.
Is there any way I can prevent this? And make sure that if a task processing certain pull request is already in progress then I wait for that to finish and then start processing it again (from the new task that was queued)

As I monitor multiple repos each with multiple PRs I would like that if an event is coming but from different repo or different pull request to start it and run it.
I only need to queue it if I already have in progress same pull request from same repo.

Any idea if this is possible with celery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way to achieve this is, setting worker concurrency to 1 so that only one task gets executed at a time.

Route the tasks to a seperate queue.

```
your_task.apply_async(foo, queue='bar')
```

Then start your worker with concurency of one

```
celery worker -Q bar -c 1
```

See also [Celery - one task in one second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26339391/celery-one-task-in-one-second/26342113#26342113)

Comment: I was thinking In having concurrency a bit higher (as it will be mostly IO and not CPU bound) with a little code at the start of the task to check for a certain key in redis. If that key is present then it was set by other job and I will have a while True sleep(5 second) and check again. This way the risk is that sometime I will keep some workers in this sleep which should happen very rare but I will not need to worry about multiple queues (setting up a new one each time I add new repo to be monitored). What do you think?

Comment: If you are performing a check in the beginning, then you can set whatever concurrency you want and route however required. It should work fine.

Comment: I'll start with different queues as It would also make sense to have one queue per repo and then see about this check that can be performed in the beginning of the task.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a [mutex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutex). For Celery, there is [`celery_mutex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/celery_mutex/0.1.0) and [`celery_once`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/celery_once/0.1). In particular, `celery_once` claims to be doing what you ask, but I do not have experience with it.

You could also use the Python [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) that has a global mutex implementation, or use a shared storage that you already have.

If the tasks run on the same machine, the operating system has locking mechanisms.